# Use on-click for a treemapify object in R Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Is it possible to do an "On-click" event to a treemapify object in R Shiny? I've tested the below code for other types of ggplot2 objects and it works. Also, if there is another way to do an "On-click" event for a treemap, please let me know!

`global.R`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(treemapify)
library(shiny)
source("functions.R")

mt <- data.frame(mtcars)
cylinders <- unique(mt$cyl)
```

`functions.R`

```
tmapData <- function(act_cyl) {
  play <- mt %>%
    mutate(name = row.names(mtcars)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(cyl == act_cyl)
  return(play)
}

tmapPlot <- function(act_cyl) {

 play <- tmapData(act_cyl)
 p <- ggplot(play, aes(area = wt, fill = mpg, label = name)) +
   geom_treemap() +
   geom_treemap_text(grow = FALSE, reflow = TRUE, color = "black")
 return(p)
}
```

`server.R`

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  active_cyl <- reactive({
    input$cyl_input
  })

  output$tmap <- renderPlot({
    tmapPlot(active_cyl())
  })

  output$tdata <- DT::renderDataTable(
    out <- DT::datatable({
      tmapData(active_cyl()) %>%
        select(name, mpg, wt)
    })
  )

  output$out_text <- renderPrint({
    nearPoints(mt, input$tClick, threshold = 10,
               maxpoints = 1, addDist = TRUE)
  })  
})
```

`ui.R`

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("nearPoints Test"),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        selectInput("cyl_input", "Number of Cylinders",
                    choices = cylinders)
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(8, h3("First Column"), plotOutput("tmap", click = "tClick")),
        column(4, h3("Second Column"), DT::dataTableOutput("tdata"))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        verbatimTextOutput("out_text")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding this correctly:

```
output$out_text <- renderPrint({
  nearPoints(mt, input$tClick, threshold = 10,
             maxpoints = 1, addDist = TRUE)
})
```

the idea is that `out_text` will tell you what observation in `mt` corresponds to the treemap tile that was clicked. However, the problem is that the x and y coordinates in the treemap don't map on to the underlying dataset in a direct way. The tile layout algorithm is dependent on the entire set of observations, so you can't predict where any single observation will be drawn without computing the entire treemap.

The solution is to precompute the treemap layout with the `treemapify()` function, then to use those coordinates to figure out which observation a clicked coordinate pair relates to:

`global.R`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(treemapify)
library(shiny)
source("functions.R")

mt <- data.frame(mtcars)
cylinders <- unique(mt$cyl)
```

`functions.R`

```
tmapData <- function() {
  play <- mt %>%
    mutate(name = row.names(mtcars)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(cyl == 4)
  return(play)
}

tmapCoords <- function() {
  treemapify(tmapData(), area = "wt", fill = "mpg", label = "name", xlim = c(0, 1),
             ylim = c(0, 1))
}

tmapPlot <- function() {

 play <- tmapData()
 p <- ggplot(play, aes(area = wt, fill = mpg, label = name)) +
   geom_treemap() +
   geom_treemap_text(grow = FALSE, reflow = TRUE, color = "black")
 return(p)
}
```

`server.R`

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$tmap <- renderPlot({
    tmapPlot()
  })

  output$tdata <- DT::renderDataTable(
    out <- DT::datatable({
      tmapData() %>%
        select(name, mpg, wt)
    })
  )

  output$out_text <- renderPrint({
    input$tClick
    tmapCoords() %>%
      filter(xmin < input$tClick$x) %>%
      filter(xmax > input$tClick$x) %>%
      filter(ymin < input$tClick$y) %>%
      filter(ymax > input$tClick$y)
  })
})
```

`ui.R`

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("nearPoints Test"),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(8, h3("First Column"), plotOutput("tmap", click = "tClick")),
        column(4, h3("Second Column"), DT::dataTableOutput("tdata"))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        verbatimTextOutput("out_text")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Everything you said makes sense. Will have to convert this over to the actual app!